# picking up random numbers from a text file in c++

Tags: visual-c++

If a text file contains numbers in 100 rows * 100 columns (for example). Now i want my program to pick up ,for example , one number from 60th row and 97th column and then assign this value to a variable and perform some calculation with this variable. So i want to pick up some random numbers from a text file which contains a lot of numbers. how can i do that??
I made a code for practice but its giving some error. 
the text file contains 6 different digits in 2 rows and 3 columns

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
 int data[6],i=0;
 ifstream myfile;
 myfile.open ("a.txt");
 while (i<<6)
       {
        myfile>>data[i];
        i=i+1;
       }
 myfile.close();
 cout<<data[0]<<"\t"<<data[1]<<"\t"<<data[2]<<"\t"<<data[3]<<"\t"<<data[4]<<"\t"   <<data[5]<<"\n";
 system("pause");
 return 0;
```

}

Comment: I have some questions: why is the size of data just 6? You mean, a text file contains numbers in 100 rows * 100 columns? What do you mean by i<<6? Do you mean maybe for (int i=0; i<6; i++)?

Comment: the code is written just for the sake of example. for this code , the text file contains 6 numbers (2 rows, 3 columns)

Comment: can you please help why its not giving output with simple while loop ?

Comment: And what about while (i<<6)? Do you mean while (i < 6) ?

Comment: O my God !! it was really a silly mistake :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (i < 6)
{
   myfile>>data[i];
   i=i+1;
}
```

Comment: And how does it say it picks random numbers?